# Return more than one row from a specific table in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, return-value

I am currently working on a private messaging system. Right now I'm coding the inbox and have put 2 rows of temporary data in my messages table to test the inbox is working correctly.

I am trying to return all rows where this query is true:

```
<?php
class Messages_model extends CI_Model {


    public function inbox()
    {
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_id = $user_id AND to_user = '$username'"); //to_id = id of currently logged in and to_user = username
    }
}
```

Here's my controller. I'm currently only having one row returned even though both rows should be returned. I have created both rows in the db with the to_id and to_user equal to my session data. So they should both be returned not just one. When I use row_array the first row is returned as explained in CI user guide. When I use result_array() still only one row is returned.

What I want to do is create a table in html with a few columns and 1 row for title of each column e.g. subject, status, date. Then the row underneath will be the actual subject data and status of the message. Then I want to run a while or foreach loop that will echo that empty row each time a row is returned from the messages table for the inbox.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class Messages extends Public_Controller {
    public function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('messages_model');

    }

    public function inbox()
    {


        $query = $this->messages_model->inbox(); // return from model which is basically a row from messages table
        if ($query->num_rows() != 0) // if rows returned is equal to 1

        {       
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) // give array variable the value row_array

        // grab specific elements from row and assign to variables
        $row['id'];
        $row['to_id'];
        $row['to_user'];
        $row['from_id'];
        $row['from_user'];
        $row['time_sent'];
        $row['subject'];
        $row['message'];
        $row['opened'];
        $row['replied'];

        $this->load->view('messages/inbox', $row);
        }

       else
        {
            echo "You have 0 messages in your inbox";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I was clear with explain what I'm trying to do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, bear in mind that I am not very familiar with CodeIgniter.  Your problem, however, is fairly generic PHP:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) // give array variable the value row_array

    // grab specific elements from row and assign to variables
    $row['id'];
    $row['to_id'];
    $row['to_user'];
    $row['from_id'];
    $row['from_user'];
    $row['time_sent'];
    $row['subject'];
    $row['message'];
    $row['opened'];
    $row['replied'];

    $this->load->view('messages/inbox', $row);
}
```

Every time you encounter a row, you're calling `$this->load->view()`.  I believe you should only be calling the view once, with all the data you want to pass.  You probably want to do something like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $data[] = array (
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'to_id' => $row['to_id'],
        'to_user' => $row['to_user'],
        'from_id' => $row['from_id'],
        'from_user' => $row['from_user'],
        'time_sent' => $row['time_sent'],
        'subject' => $row['subject'],
        'message' => $row['message'],
        'opened' => $row['opened'],
        'replied' => $row['replied']
    );
}
$this->load->view('messages/inbox', $data);
```

You would then need to process multiple messages in your view.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I should do the foreach loop in the actual view because I'm getting undefined variable this way but I didn't didn't want to put that much php in my view but I guess this is ok for the inbox table.

Comment: @Psychonetics A loop in your view makes perfect semantic sense if it is needed.

Comment: Still having trouble with this. I was thinking of passing the output of the inbox method in my model to the view but that would be bad practice. What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorted. $data=['query'] = $query->row_array();

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing braces in your for loop:

```
 foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) // give array variable the value row_array
 {
    // grab specific elements from row and assign to variables
    $row['id'];
    $row['to_id'];
    $row['to_user'];
    $row['from_id'];
    $row['from_user'];
    $row['time_sent'];
    $row['subject'];
    $row['message'];
    $row['opened'];
    $row['replied'];
 }
```

A for loop only applies to the first line unless you surround the body in braces.